# Rendering custom emoji through an IME

Tags: android, unicode, ime, emoticons

I am thinking about making a keyboard (for myself and a few friends) with the sprites of the 721 Pokémon in it. First, however, I need to figure out a good way to store these characters. My idea was to store these in unused Unicode characters, but I need 721 of them.

Is there a better way to have custom emoji without overwriting existing ones? If not, what are 721 characters I can use (preferably together, no breaks in between) to store the Pokémon?

As a bonus, how can I store the shiny versions of these Pokémon?

Then, how do I draw these characters using my keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

**Encoding**

You probably want to store them in a Private Use Area (PUA) block.
There are 3 of them, I would use one of the supplementary ones, as the risk to stumble on someone's else private use is reduced.
Don't override the existing ones.

**Rendering**

You will need to use your own font and embed it in your application.

You will need a way to tell the text engine "hey, for characters in this range use this font". So you need some rich text format (i.e. HTML), so use a WebView.
TextView might also work, if you use a Spanned created Html.fromHtml. But I am not sure if that supports specifying an embedded font, need to try.

**Input**

You would need a custom keyboard... There might be some open source, data driven one. Or one in the store that allows you to customize it. Or you can add them to the   dictionary, with a shortcut, but then you will need to know all the names (so that you can type p.pikachu). Or you can use a character picker.

**Storage**

At this point they are strings. You can store as any other text, move through the wire, on disk, etc.

Comment: In rendering, you say "You will need to use your own font and embed it in your application." What do you mean by that? And how do I make this work in apps like Hangouts, Messenger, etc? Also, the PUAs are after FFFF (they're in UTF-16?), will this affect anything? And for the keyboard, I saw a keyboard that used SVGs of its own to replace the smiley emoji. Will I be able to extend this?

Comment: Sorry, not SVGs, PNGs, here it is: https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard I see that it uses Spanned HTML, how does that work?

Comment: * "use your own font and embed it in your application" => useTypeface.createFromAsset (example here: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/using-external-fonts-in-android-view)

Comment: * "work in apps like Hangouts, Messenger, etc" => you can't, not unless you have a rooted device and hack an existing, system font

Comment: * "the PUAs are after FFFF" => there are 3 blocks, one below FFFF, 2 above (E000..F8FF, F0000..FFFFF, 100000..10FFFF)

Comment: * "will this affect anything" => nope, if you are careful. The existing emojis are also above FFFF (1F600..1F64F)

Comment: * "I saw a keyboard that used SVGs of its own to replace the smiley emoji" => I don't know, depends on the creator of that keyboard. I did not look at the code.

Comment: * Looking at the requirement to support Hangouts and other apps, it looks like a font is not the way to go. Would need to use bitmaps (PNG, or, even better, WebP, but needs Android 4.2.1+). But bitmaps means a completely different approach, it is not text anymore. Problems with storing, network communication, etc.

Comment: * "github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard" => I looked at the code. It does not look like a real keyboard, despite the name. It is just an application, and inserts bitmaps in a TextEdit it owns. With the bitmaps embedded. So it can't be used to type in Hangouts, or anything else. Try it...

Comment: Exactly why I want do delete this question, it's not possible.